# Append parsed data

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a python code for data parsing from web-site. It' working fine, script is opening both pages, but in output I am receiving data only from last page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

mylist = ['93729', '75077']

for i in mylist:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get('https://www.comicshoplocator.com/StoreLocator')
    driver.maximize_window()
    d = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'query')
    d.send_keys(i)
    d.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_="LocationName"):
        print(tag.text)
```

My current output is:

```
TWENTY ELEVEN COMICS
READ COMICS
BOOMERANG COMICS
MORE FUN COMICS AND GAMES
MADNESS COMICS & GAMES
SANCTUARY BOOKS AND GAMES
```

Desirable output is:

```
HEROES COMICS
TWENTY ELEVEN COMICS
READ COMICS
BOOMERANG COMICS
MORE FUN COMICS AND GAMES
MADNESS COMICS & GAMES
SANCTUARY BOOKS AND GAMES
```

Keep in mind -- current list of zip-codes is for testing. I need a versatile solution for list with 10 or more items.

Thanks!

Comment: When I run your code I get the desired output. Maybe you need to add some sleeps or waits? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: @dosas I have tried adding a sleep, but it does not help. Are you sure you have a HEROES COMICS on the top of your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are generating the output of the both iterations but separately for each loop. So,I use pandas DataFrame for the final output. As dosas stated ,yes,need load time

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))#,options=options

mylist = ['93729', '75077']
data=[]
for i in mylist:   
    
    driver.get('https://www.comicshoplocator.com/StoreLocator')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    d = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'query')
    d.send_keys(i)
    d.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    
    for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_="LocationName"):
        title=tag.text
        data.append({
            'title':title
        })
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 title
0              HEROES COMICS
1       TWENTY ELEVEN COMICS
2                READ COMICS
3           BOOMERANG COMICS
4  MORE FUN COMICS AND GAMES
5     MADNESS COMICS & GAMES
6  SANCTUARY BOOKS AND GAMES
```